Electrical Circuits - How does AC voltage/current propagate?
Several years post grad, I've been studying from Halliday et al.'s "Physics Volume 2, 5ed." and various articles online including Network Analysis, particularly on Impedance (i.e. not a Homework question). I've come across the notion that AC voltage sources take the form:
$$V(t) := |V(t)|e^{j(\omega t+\phi_V)}.$$
If we assume one dimension of oscillation is along the wire that transmits the current, there is still a 2D disc cross-section that leaves a choice for the other oscillation direction. Am I missing something? How does AC voltage propagate?
If instead, we assumed it oscillated only in the cross-sectional directions, the electrons couldn't make it down the line to energize the other circuit elements? Any thoughts on this are appreciated

Not quite a duplicate but very closely related and probably answers your question:  What is the physical significance of the imaginary part when plane waves are represented as $e^{i(kx-\omega t)}$?

What do you mean by "other oscillation direction"? There is only one. Also note that if you're considering wires of finite thickness, the majority of AC current is near the surface due to the skin effect.

Are you talking about a circuit with an alternating emf source or an electromagnetic wave propagating down a transmission line? The former doesn't "propagate" while the latter does.

@VincentThacker "AC voltage source" a.k.a. emf. But I am interested now in EM wave too since you mention it.

You know the frequency of a signal. Thus you can calculate associated wavelength. If it is much higher then the physical size of the circuit, then no propagation occur. Otherwise there is propagation. It is well known in microwave circuits. There are transmission lines for example consisting of a "wire" and "ground" where the wave propagates.

Anyway imagine low frequency so no propagation occur. Foe optics or radio wave there is propagation. And there is something in between.

There is already a propagation for several GHz of frequency where 3GhHz correspond to 10cm. It means that for that  size there is propagation

Much smaller circuits are considered from lumped elements otherwise electric impedance, capacitance  etc should be considered for unit lenght


Why is the dimension of AC oscillation 2 and not 3?

An alternating current does not oscillate in 2 or 3 dimensions - it is an oscillation of voltage (or alternatively of current) which can be positive or negative but does not have a direction in 2 or 3 dimensional space. So AC only oscillates in one dimension.
However, it is useful to model an AC voltage mathematically as if it were the projection onto one axis of a point rotating around a circle in two-dimensional space. And a convenient way to represent this mathematically is to introduce a complex valued variable $e^{i \omega t}$ and then take the voltage to be proportional to the real valued component of this.
In the same way, a particle executing simple harmonic motion (such as a simple pendulum) only has one degree of freedom, so it is only oscillating in one dimension. But its displacement can be modelled mathematically as the real valued component of a complex valued variable which has two degrees of freedom. So we can represent the displacement $x(t)$ as the real valued part of $A e^{i \omega t}$ where $A$ is the pendulum's amplitude and $\frac {\omega}{2 \pi}$ is its frequency.

So its a push/pull basically. Thank you. The rope trick came to mind, where you tie off one end and send a pulse along it. But yes the projection is good.

The " $A e ^ {i\omega t}$" formula is the equation for a helix; it has a real and imaginary extent, as well as propagating along a time axis.
Imagine the projection of this kind of curve (picture a Slinky toy
and observe its shadow on a wall); that's a sine wave.
The equation for a resistor current versus voltage is not time-dependent,
but the equations for capacitors and inductors contain time derivative and time integrals, So, a network of those components requires a lot of math know-how to understand.
The use of the helix formulation is that the derivatives and integrals of AC sine wave components are in proportion to the imaginary parts of that helix (called also
a gyrator).  Those curves are contained in the helix's OTHER shadows, thus can be
represented by simple linear equations.   When one applies Kirchoff's
rules for setting up equations, the stage is set for treating
circuitry as if it were coupled linear equations, which has been
well-studied: you make a matrix equation, and solve it (inverting a matrix, typically) in a mechanical fashion.   Charles Proteus Steinmetz
Theory and Calculation...taught this over a century ago, and half a century ago it was
formulated into simulation software: SPICE, notably.
Adding in diodes, transistors, vacuum tubes, spark gaps: that requires
baby-step equation solving in a slightly different way, because those
components are  only linear for small signals over short timescales: your
SPICE program may have to readjust every microsecond of time
to a new matrix , adjusting the coefficients of the matrix for each
new operating point of each curve (because those elements treat AC
in a nonlinear way, and are best approximated by different linear
equations at different times).   That's called transient analysis,
and takes lots of SPICE time to do well.

From this I gather that in general, with random circuit elements, the solution for the current can be hard to calculate, even with software. And not just steady-state. But this calculation, with Kirchoff, similar to using Maxwell, land us back at square one I feel. We have some complex valued expression for current/voltage. But how does it physically evolve along the circuit?

It does not propagate. AC steady state circuits belongs to the quasi-static regime. The values in voltage and current in the various branch of the circuit do not propagate with a finite time. They change instantaneously in the entire circuit, without transmission or retardation effects.
Transmission lines show propagation. While still modeled by using lumped circuit elements (for each of which the respective quasi-static approximation - which uses incomplete Maxwell's equations - is still valid) they can show propagation in terms of the exchange of energy between adjacent lumped elements cells in a 'chain' that extends in the direction of the line.
A full-fledged EM description of the propagation would require all Maxwell's equations in their full form and it is usually too complex and numerically intensive to solve, so it is not the first choice to tackle this sort of problems.
(And yet, if you were to have a light-second long, say one meter wide circuit with source and load facing each other in the middle, you'd better resort to the full EM simulation, because a transmission line model would miss the propagation in the transversal direction).

Maybe "evolve" is a better term to use in the question than "propagate" according to your answer. Thank you for the input!
